# NumPy `fromstring` function works fine in Python 2.7 but returns error in Python 3.7

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, python-3.7

I use this syntax to convert the byte array dataword (2 bytes for each sample):

```
data = numpy.fromstring(dataword, dtype=numpy.int16)
```

same instruction in Python 3.7 returns the error:

```
TypeError: fromstring() argument 1 must be read-only bytes-like object, not memoryview

dataword = scope.ReadBinary(rlen-4) #dataword is a byte array, each 2 byte is an integer
data = numpy.fromstring(dataword, dtype=numpy.int16)# data is the int16 array
```

This is the content of `data` in Python 2.7.14:

```
[-1.41601562 -1.42382812 -1.42578125 ...,  1.66992188  1.65234375  1.671875  ]
```

I am expecting to get the same result with Python 3.7.

How am I supposed to use `numpy.fromstring()` in 3.7?

Comment: What is `scope`?

Comment: scope is an activex object, needed the receive the binary vector from an instrument. in python 2.7.14 dataword is defined as a binary array:              buffer: ��P��������0����@�p��p����...........

Comment: python 3.7: in the variable  tab of LIclipse i can see that dataword  is defined as memoryview:<memory at 0x0f.....   definetely not a binary vector as in python 2.17

Answer (score 1):

The `TypeError` tries to tell you that `dataword` is of the non-supported type `memoryview`.
It needs to be passed as an unmutable type, like `bytes`:

```python
data = numpy.fromstring(dataword.tobytes(), dtype=numpy.int16)
```

Even better; it seems like `scope` is a file-like object, so this could also work:

```python
data = numpy.fromfile(scope, dtype=numpy.int16, count=rlen//2-4)
```

Comment: Understood, all based on the how python3 is handling binary strings. I beleive this will work, going to try and give you an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

simple solution... found reading numpy manual: replace fromstring with frombuffer

data = numpy.frombuffer(dataword, dtype=numpy.int16)
works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

fromstring doesn't work because dataword is a memeoryview not a string, then frombuffer  musty be used

`data = numpy.frombuffer(dataword.tobytes(), dtype=numpy.int16)`